# Display return message for Ajax response from Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I've got a working form that submits to a database from an HTML form using Laravel Collective that submits to my Controller, and it works fine.

I want to submit it without a page reload, so I'm submitting the data with AJAX.

I've got it working, and it's writing to the db, but I can't get the controller to return the response to the page on success.

The following is my script:

**SCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#msg").hide();

  $("#submit").click(function() {
    $("#msg").show();


    var name = $("#recipeName").val();
    var description = $("#recipeDescription").val();
    var token = $("#token").val();

    $.ajax({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
      type: "post",
      data: "name="+name+"&description="+description,
      dataType:'json',
      url: "{{ route('recipes.store') }}",
      success:function(data){
        $("#msg").html("Recipe Saved");
        $("#msg").fadeOut(2000);

      }
    });
  })
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <p class="alert alert-success" id="msg"></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">

    <!-- Start Form -->
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="{{csrf_token()}}" id="token">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="recipeName">Recipe name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipeName" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter recipe name">
      <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="recipeDescription">Recipe Description:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="recipeDescription" rows="3" placeholder="Enter a recipe description"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" id="submit">Submit</button>
    <!-- End Form -->

  </div>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
      'name' => 'required|max:255',
      'description' => 'required'
    ]);

    $recipe = new Recipe;

    $recipe->name = $request->name;
    $recipe->description = $request->description;
    $recipe->user_id = auth()->user()->id;

    $recipe->save();

    return Response::json(array(
      'success' => true,
      'data'   => $data
    )); 
}
```

I can't workout what it is that I'm missing.

I'm learning AJAX on the fly (I'm learning all of it on the fly if I'm honest!), but as I say, it's writing to the db successfully, just need to notify the user of it.

Comment: in success:function(data){ console.log(data) - does it return anything? Is the success block running? is the msg div visible? hidden? put default content in there can you see it? dont fade it out, can you find it after success??? is the message in it?????????????????????????

Comment: Adding console.log(data) to the success I get a 500 server error.

Comment: excellent so its a serverside/php/laravel problem, try to isolate. 1 possibility, I think for ajax json requests, you can just return an array of data from the controller, and laravel will auto convert to json for u.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It looks like I was returning the response incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the following in the controller works correctly!

```
...
$recipe->save();
$data = [
  'success' => true,
  'message'=> 'Your AJAX processed correctly'
] ;

return response()->json($data);
```

Answer (score 2):

**SCRIPT**

```
  $("#submit").click(function() {
        $("#msg").show();
        var name = $("#recipeName").val();
        var description = $("#recipeDescription").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            data: {name:name,description:description,'_token':'{{csrf_token()}}'}, 
             dataType:'json',
            url: "{{ route('recipes.store') }}",
            success:function(data){
                $("#msg").html("Recipe Saved");
                $("#msg").fadeOut(2000);

            }
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

change the the type of submit button from submit to button

```
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col">
  <p class="alert alert-success" id="msg"></p>
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col">

<!-- Start Form -->
<input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="{{csrf_token()}}" id="token">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="recipeName">Recipe name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipeName" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter recipe name">
  <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="recipeDescription">Recipe Description:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="recipeDescription" rows="3" placeholder="Enter a recipe description"></textarea>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" id="submit">Submit</button>
<!-- End Form -->
```

**Controller**

you must identify $data variable

```
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
   $this->validate($request, [
   'name' => 'required|max:255',
  'description' => 'required'
]);

$data = 'some data';
$recipe = new Recipe;

$recipe->name = $request->name;
$recipe->description = $request->description;
$recipe->user_id = auth()->user()->id;

$recipe->save();

return Response::json(array(
  'success' => true,
  'data'   => $data
)); 
}
```

Comment: As above, getting a 500 error on this, even with the change above.

Comment: I am waiting your response

Comment: I've posted a solution above. Looks like the tutorial I was using was returning the response incorrectly. The following worked: `return response()->json($data);`. Thanks for your help.